# Changing KDE system setting using only terminal

Tags: debian, kde

I recently successfully dual-booted Windows 11 with Debian 12 (KDE Plasma), but I am unable to click with the touchpad.

When I checked the settings in the devices section, I noticed that the `tap to click` option is not toggled, and since tapping on the touchpad doesn't work, I'm unable to enable it manually.

Could you please provide me with a way to toggle that option using just the terminal?

Comment: Usually in a graphical environment the tab key will step you around the screen to things that you can focus on, then enter performs the click.  Alternatively there may be a configuration file behind the scenes that you can edit and change a setting from false to true (or something equivalent)

Comment: Thanks @PonJar , it worked. `Tab` key worked to step around the options and then space bar for ctoggling it then Ctrl+Q to quit where it asked to save or not and again tab key did that.